# Get values off an opportunity child object to update multiselect picklist field

Tags: apex

I have a new multi-select picklist field on opportunity that needs to be updated with values from an opportunity child object. Here's how the data looks when queried via workbench..

[image: Opportunity products]

I'm looking to get the data in a similar format below in order to update the picklist field.

Opportunity Id => Retail;Retail90;Mail

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Btw, multi-picklist values are common for all opportunities as they are metadata. But here each of the opty could have different set of values. So how would you reconcile and show those values?

Comment: @singularity that's what I'm looking for - a way to iterate over the list so that for every opportunity id, get me corresponding product values as a string separated by semi-colon.

Comment: If you want to achieve this, you will have to build a new VF page to edit that field of opportunity. In the init part of the page, retrieve the list of values and show them as possible options.

Comment: an alternative is to write an after update/insert/delete/undelete trigger on OLI that updates the parent Opportunity's MSP field with the unique values from all children OLI of that Oppo - there are numerous SFSE examples that show this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across an excel solution, did an extract via the dataloader then did some vba magic to get me what I wanted. Here's the link: https://superuser.com/questions/536234/excel-how-to-vlookup-to-return-multiple-values
Looks like this..

[image]